# Jacckson возвращает null

Tags: java, json, spring, null, jackson

При десериализации json строки, получаемой с сервера https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js Jackson возращает null. Скачивал сам файл и пытался десериализовать через него - тоже null. Пробовал через методы readValue и getForObject - null. Сервер корректно отдаёт и сам файл и строку в виде json.
Что не так?

JSON:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

МОИ КЛАССЫ:

```
@Data
@ToString(of = {"date", "previousDate", "previousUrl", "timeStamp", "valute"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"date", "previousDate", "previousUrl", "timeStamp", "valute"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class ExchangeRates implements Serializable {

private Date date;
private Date previousDate;
private String previousUrl;
private Date timeStamp;
private Map<String, Valute> valute;
```

}

```
@Data
@ToString(of = {"id", "numCode", "charCode", "nominal", "name", "value", "previous"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "numCode", "charCode", "nominal", "name", "value", "previous"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Valute implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private Integer numCode;
    private String charCode;
    private Integer nominal;
    private String name;
    private Double value;
    private Double previous;
}
```

КОНТРОЛЛЕР:

```
@RestController
public class ValuteController {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${application.json-files-dir}")
    private String jsonFileDir;

    @Value("${application.cbr-daily-json}")
    private String URL;

    @Autowired
    public ValuteController(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public void getData(Model model) {
        File file = new File(jsonFileDir + "ExchangeRates.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ExchangeRates exchangeRates = null;

        try {
            exchangeRates = mapper.readValue(file, ExchangeRates.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(exchangeRates);
    }

    private String getEmployees() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                URL,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                entity,
                String.class
        );

        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        return response.getBody();
```

И НАСТРОЙКА RestTemplate:

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Зависимости в POM:

```
<!--Jackson-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
            </dependency>
        <!--Jackson-->
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:

```
ExchangeRates(date=null, previousDate=null, previousUrl=null, timeStamp=null, valute=null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас отличается маппинг в классе и json, т.к. в json поля именуются с заглавной буквы, от чего Jackson не может сопоставить поля.
Вам надо проставить над соответсвующими полями @JsonProperty с соответсвующим ключом из json. Например, в json есть поле Date, у вас date, соответсвенно полю date надо добавить @JsonProperty(name = "Date")

Comment: Вы правы. Нашёл проблему сам, но всё же спасибо!)

Comment: @АмирДигиев проблем была в именовании полей?

Comment: @Jackson750, да